# How to disable laptop keyboard on plugging in a USB keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I use my USB keyboard in home and now I want disable  the laptop keyboard on plug of this keyboard.

How could I achieve this?

I use ArchLinux and DWM.

ps:
i found my device and in udev disable it

```
xinput disable 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to accomplish this?

Comment: @jippie some times, some people work with my laptop keyboard and its bad :D i use  my keyboard and monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a udev script that floats the built-in keyboard using `xinput`.