# How to disable Internal Keyboard on Fedora 26 (Wayland)?

Tags: fedora, gnome, wayland

I installed Fedora 26 and noticed that the Internal keyboard is behaving a bit weird. Keys are getting pressed all the time.

I use an external keyboard, so I can do without the built-in one.

P.S : This is not a duplicate of [How to disable laptop keyboard on plugging in a USB keyboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39663/how-to-disable-laptop-keyboard-on-plugging-in-a-usb-keyboard) as the answer is for Xorg and not for wayland

Answer (score 8):

I'm not able to try this, but perhaps you can "grab" input from the unwanted device using `evtest` so that they are not delivered to other processes. Find the device from `ls /dev/input/by-id/`. For example, I have `/dev/input/by-id/usb-05f3_0007-event-kbd` which is a symbolic link to `../event2`. Presumably for a built-in keyboard there should be a similar non-usb "kbd". 
You can then try

```
sudo evtest --grab /dev/input/event2
```

on the appropriate file or link.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but when I run `ls /dev/input/by-id` the following devices are shown.  


`usb-SIGMACHIP_Usb_Mouse-event-mouse@  usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-if01@  usb-Vimicro_corp._Lenovo_EasyCamera-event-if00@
usb-SIGMACHIP_Usb_Mouse-mouse@        usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd@
`  

If I disable `kdb` keyboard the external keyboard stops working, and when I try to disable the `if01` nothing happens, and both keyboards work like magic.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but

Comment: Your other keyboard might be listed as `/dev/input/by-path/platform*kbd`.

Comment: Nop, still does not work,

Comment: `sudo evtest --grab /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd` does the trick for me.

Comment: sorry, how is it supposed to work? do you keep a terminal with evtest running all the time?

Comment: @robertspierre yes, the grab is done only whilst the process has the device open. You can redirect the output to /dev/null, or you can probably background the process so that it no longer gets the cpu, but still has the device open. Alternatively, look at using [udev](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-configuration-via-udev.html#ignoring-devices) to permanently ignore a device.

Comment: @meuh done, thanks :) I posted a detailed guide later

Answer (score 4):

**How to disable the keyboard with udev**

This will allow you to disable the keyboard with udev rules, without a process running in the background all the time.

1. Run `sudo evtest`. This will list the device and the name of all your input device. If the device is `/dev/input/eventX`, then your "device event number" is `X`. For example, my internal keyboard is listed as:

   ```
   /dev/input/event4:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
   ```

   So my "device event number" is 4.
2. `evtest` asks you the "device event number". Type it in (in my case it is `4`) and press ENTER. Make sure the events of the keyboard are captured, then close the process with `CTRL+C`
3. Run

   ```
   udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=$(udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/input/eventX)
   ```

   where `/dev/input/eventX` is the device found previously. This will list udev rules that match the device and its parent. See [archlinux udev documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev#udev_rule_example) for more details.

   In my case this lists:

   ```
   Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
   walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
   found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
   A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
   and the attributes from one single parent device.

     looking at device '/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4':
       KERNEL=="event4"
       SUBSYSTEM=="input"
       DRIVER==""
       ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
       ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
       ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
       ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

     looking at parent device '/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4':
       KERNELS=="input4"
       SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
       DRIVERS==""
       ATTRS{capabilities/abs}=="0"
       ATTRS{capabilities/ev}=="120013"
       ATTRS{capabilities/ff}=="0"
       ATTRS{capabilities/key}=="10000 c020000000000 0 0 700f02000003 3802078f870f401 febfffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe"
       ATTRS{capabilities/led}=="7"
       ATTRS{capabilities/msc}=="10"
       ATTRS{capabilities/rel}=="0"
       ATTRS{capabilities/snd}=="0"
       ATTRS{capabilities/sw}=="0"
       ATTRS{id/bustype}=="0011"
       ATTRS{id/product}=="0001"
       ATTRS{id/vendor}=="0001"
       ATTRS{id/version}=="ab41"
       ATTRS{inhibited}=="0"
       ATTRS{name}=="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
       ATTRS{phys}=="isa0060/serio0/input0"
       ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
       ATTRS{properties}=="0"
       ATTRS{uniq}==""

     looking at parent device '/devices/platform/i8042/serio0':
       KERNELS=="serio0"
       SUBSYSTEMS=="serio"
       DRIVERS=="atkbd"
       ATTRS{bind_mode}=="auto"
       ATTRS{description}=="i8042 KBD port"
       ATTRS{drvctl}=="(write-only)"
       ATTRS{err_count}=="0"
       ATTRS{extra}=="0"
       ATTRS{firmware_id}=="PNP: PNP0303"
       ATTRS{force_release}=="369-370"
       ATTRS{id/extra}=="00"
       ATTRS{id/id}=="00"
       ATTRS{id/proto}=="00"
       ATTRS{id/type}=="06"
       ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
       ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
       ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
       ATTRS{scroll}=="0"
       ATTRS{set}=="2"
       ATTRS{softraw}=="1"
       ATTRS{softrepeat}=="0"

     looking at parent device '/devices/platform/i8042':
       KERNELS=="i8042"
       SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
       DRIVERS=="i8042"
       ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
       ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

     looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
       KERNELS=="platform"
       SUBSYSTEMS==""
       DRIVERS==""
       ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
       ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
   ```
4. Build a udev rule that match you device and its parent, and that only. Make sure it is run last by naming it with a high number at the start.

   Once you matched the device, set its `LIBINPUT_IGNORE_DEVICE` option to anything other than 0 (for example, 1). See the [libinput guide on ignoring specific devices](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-configuration-via-udev.html#ignoring-specific-devices) for more details.

   For example, here is my `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ignore-my-device.rules`:

   ```
   KERNELS=="input4", SUBSYSTEMS=="input", ATTRS{id/product}=="0001", ATTRS{id/vendor}=="0001", ATTRS{id/version}=="ab41", ENV{LIBINPUT_IGNORE_DEVICE}="1"
   ```
5. Reboot your device. udev rules are applied only to newly connected devices, not to devices already connected.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Wayland compositor creates an abstract for the keyboard so all client couldn't see the hardware keyboard.
I tried as below and it works:

```
sudo libinput list-devices
```

In my case, in my case, it leads to /dev/input/event6. Then you can use evtest as meuh's answer.

Comment: BTW, you can also just run `evtest`, and it will list all event devices.

Comment: @dirkt `evtest` lists both the vendor ID and product ID of my integrated keyboard as `0x1`