# Disable device with libinput

Tags: fedora, libinput, yubikey

I want to disable a keyboard input device with `libinput`. Something analogous to:

```
xinput set-int-prop 1 "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

which follows the syntax:

> --set-int-prop device property format value
>
> Sets an integer property for the device. Appropriate values for format are 8, 16, or 32, depending on the property. Deprecated, use --set-prop instead.

(or like `xinput set-prop`).

I want to use this to disable a keyboard-emulating authentication dongle (Yubikey) from "typing out" out a token from a spurious touch.

Perhaps there is a preferred method not involving `libinput` to do this. I do not want to disable the dongle completely, as it has features other than generating a token through its keyboard emulation (it is a GPG smart card too).

I am using Fedora 26 with Wayland.

Comment: Just for the sake of documentation, using xinput, you can also disable a device running `xinput disable <id>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Internal Keyboard on Fedora 26 (Wayland)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381944/how-to-disable-internal-keyboard-on-fedora-26-wayland)

Answer (score 2):

fwiw, the `LIBINPUT_IGNORE_DEVICE` udev property can be assigned to devices that should be ignored. Detailed docs are here:

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-configuration-via-udev.html#ignoring-devices

Comment: If the device is both keyboard and mouse, I wonder, if you can disable only one of them temporarily, if desired?

Comment: Depends. The udev property works per kernel device, so per event node. Some physical devices expose multiple event nodes for different capabilities - that's quite common. Since they're different event nodes, you can disable them. Rarer are those that expose one event node with multiple capabilities and you cannot disable parts of those (they are only libinput device, the xf86-input-libinput driver may split them into multiple X devices though but that's not needed under Wayland).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any method involving `libinput`, but you can do an exclusive grab on the `/dev/input/event*` device that corresponds to the Yubikey. This works on the kernel input layer, with an `ioctl`, and prevents any other application (e.g. Wayland using `libinput`) from processing events from this device.

Normally whatever program that intends to use features on the Yubikey should do the grab, but you can test it out with `evtest --grab` and choosing the Yubikey, or `evtest --grab /dev/input/eventX` if you know the device or a symlink to it.

The `ioctl` is `EVIOCGRAB`, defined in `/usr/include/linux/input.h`, in case you want to use it from a program. Also works with Python and other scripting languages that can do `iotctl`s.