# How can I disable laptop keyboard without carrying a terminal around all the time?

Tags: fedora, keyboard, laptop, wayland

I have Fedora Workstation 36 running Wayland.

I need to disable the keyboard that comes with my laptop, without keeping a terminal open all the time.

The solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381944/how-to-disable-internal-keyboard-on-fedora-26-wayland) is to run:

```
sudo evtest --grab /dev/input/event2
```

but this requires to keep a terminal open at all times, plus a background process running all time.

Comment: Create a `.desktop` file?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov and run it every time the PC starts?

Comment: No idea, you've not specified your use case and requirements.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov my use case is that the keyboard of the laptop is broken and I'm using an external USB keyboard. The requirements are: deactivate laptop's keyboard in Fedora Workstation 36 running Wayland, possibly through config and not through a background process constantly running.

Comment: @robertspierre - find out what driver it uses and locate it in /sys/bus/... - you should be able to unbind the device... for example, i unbind my integrated camera in my laptop, like so: 'echo '1-4' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind'... you won't need a terminal open for this and you could script it and/or at it as a systemd service on boot.

Comment: @jrdnjhntsn I need more details on "find out what driver it uses" and "locate it in /sys/bus/" please :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard - add this to `rc.local` or create a systemd unit. GOOGLE knows everything.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov there's no `xinput` on Wayland

Comment: You're right, sorry, googling hasn't revealed anything interesting, also someone has already asked the question and no one replied: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671972/disable-latptop-keyboard-on-wayland-gnome

Comment: It's above me why people insist on using half-assed Wayland. Sorry. I cannot call this abomination a graphics system, it's a crap system for those who want to have nothing but troubles.

Comment: Funnily someone else has asked the same question today almost at the same time as you: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-disable-laptop-keyboard-on-wayland/22414

Comment: @robertspierre - google "linux unbind usb": there are examples on the web on how to do this -- but you will need to know what device/bus your keyboard is on... as it's a laptop, it's likely in /sys/bus/usb, but it could be elsewhere, maybe /sys/bub/hid

Comment: you should be able to identify your keyboard by using 'lsmod' or 'lsusb', etc. then navigating through /sys/bus or sys/devices/platform, etc to find it in sysfs / the file system

Comment: I've achieved it and posted instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702857/271811). Marking this as a duplicate of that one :)