# how to make mouse and keyboard work again after disabled all input devices

Tags: linux, wayland, laptop, hid

I want to disable internal keyboard of my laptap, then I followed [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702857/573951) and [this doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dell_XPS_13_(9343)#Disable_the_touchscreen) (because it's Ubuntu and Wayland)

so I created a `.rules` includes:

```
KERNELS=="input2",
ATTRS{name}=="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard",
ENV{LIBINPUT_IGNORE_DEVICE}="1"
```

finally I reboot Ubuntu. But I found I can't use mouse and external keyboard too.(seems like it disabled all input devices...)

How should I fix it?

> my ubuntu is in U disk, so I can open it in VMware, but still can't use mouse and keyboard.
> and I didn't config ssh on it, so seems couldn't access by using other machine 
> Is there some ways can make my mouse and keyboard work again?

Comment: the title of your post does not match the question you are asking

Comment: Is the last paragraph really a citation? If not, i.e. if it's information about your setup, does it mean the Ubuntu in question is a virtual machine and Windows is the host? Quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

sorry my question is confusing. It does, It's information about my setup. it's a "ubuntu to go" in a U disk and Windows is the host. 
I solved it minutes ago, I delete the file by using Diskgenius in host. I can use my devices again.
sorry again, perhaps someone can delete this confusing question now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).